# How to read XML styled text file in java?

Tags: java, dom, jaxb

I want to read below XML file in Java which is in text format,

**XML File:**

```
    <Sample>
     <DATA>
       <ID>12345</ID>
       <NAME>Person1</NAME>
       <MAIL>sa@gmail.com</MAIL>
       <Class>A&B</Class>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
       <ID>12345</ID>
       <NAME>Person1</NAME>
       <MAIL>sa@gmail.com</MAIL>
       <Class>A<B</Class>
    </DATA>
   </Sample>
```

I was used JAXB to read this xml file, for this i have added a POJO class too with annotation. While unmarshalling the XMl file am getting a below exception

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException : The entity must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.]
```

Can any one suggest me a best approach to read this xml?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not valid XML. You should ask the creator of that XML to either properly escape the `&` and the like, or wrap them in a CDATA section. And this is the reason, why one should not generate XML by simple String processing (unless great care is taken)

Comment: @GyroGearless  : Don't know whether they will do this or not. Will check with them.Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

See [link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/beware-of-the-ampersand-when-using-xml/) - as stated by the error, the XML expects an entity reference. You'll need to use `&amp;`, and `&gt;` for that greater-than symbol. The Saxon library you are using should process these URLencoded characters correctly.

> When the XML parser finds an ampersand in the XML data, it expects to find a symbol name and a semicolon following it. The symbol name provides a symbolic reference to another entity or character such as the ampersand, greater-than, and less-than characters.

Comment: Yeah am getting this file from some external source, i have tried with **StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(xml)** commons.lang package method which replace all "<,>,",',&" with respective html entity &gt;,&lt;,&amp;. But if i unmashall this content am getting xml parse exception.

Comment: Well, unless you are being given valid XML, you won't be able to unmashall, parse, or otherwise process it as xml. As others have stated above, unless you can get the source to send valid XML, you'll need to use regex to find and replace unmatched `<` and `>` and `&`s without a symbol and semicolon.